# Which is correct? "While supplies last" or "while supply lasts?"

Tags: grammatical-number

For marketing copy, is it correct to say "while supplies last" or "while supply lasts?"  I've most often seen "supplies last" but I suppose "supply lasts" could be correct, too, depending on how you interpret supply as a noun - as in "we have a supply of items" versus "we have supplies of items."

Comment: Either is valid (assuming the plurality of "supply" can be accounted for).  "While supplies last" is, as you noted, more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'We have a supply of items' is fine and is in the count-mass grey area (?/*We have two supplies of items.)

'While supply lasts' is forcing a more mass usage on this sense, which sounds unnatural.

'While our / the / this year's supply lasts' sounds less outlandish. 'While supplies last' is by far the more usual non-determiner(etc)-accompanied usage.

Comment: I agree *while **the** [current] supply lasts* sounds less "outlandish", but I'm also a bit inclined to interpret *while supply lasts* as being a reference to *while the supply **chain/route** lasts*. Perhaps it's just that when we hear a non-idiomatic twist on a standard usage, we're inclined to be a bit creative in making assumptions about what exactly the speaker meant. (Unless he's obviously a non-native speaker, obviously! :)