# Is there a special name for that kind of product category?

Tags: single-word-requests, category, products

I'm making a webshop and I can't find a good name for a special category.

Is there any name for a category that holds products which will be no longer sold after the stock has been run out? In hungarian there is a name "Kifutó" for it, which means that these products are the last ones. But these are not "last" pieces, there could be a lot of them (maybe more than 1000), the name should means that we stop selling these goods after all of them has been bought. Or should I just call it "LAST PRODUCTS"? But I wouldn't like to suggest that there are only a few pieces left.

Thanks

Comment: Kind of answered by  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292352/which-is-correct-while-supplies-last-or-while-supply-lasts

Comment: "closeouts" is a common term for items where inventory will be sold until gone - it doesn't necessarily imply that there will only be a few left of something recently put on closeout but it might imply that there could be fewer choices of sizes and colors for closeout items that had been there for a while - "Ending soon" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In certain business sectors products have a "life-cycle". For example electronic components you might have a product that goes from first **New**, then transition to a **Last-time-buy**, then **End-of-life**, and finally **Discontinued**. The reason being that those components may need to still be supported because they are a part for other products that are still being made.  Using this example, even if your products don't undergo any sort of life-cycle, you could use the term "Last Time Buy" to indicate that once the stock is sold you won't have any more.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I hear ads from sellers getting rid of old stock they say "stocktake sale."

A stock-take sale is a sale with reduced prices in a shop designed to sell off stock from previous seasons. 
[Stock-taking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock-taking)

It think it implies that someone is getting rid of old inventory. I don't know if this applies to your case.